# Render ASP in pages with .html extension in Windows CE

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-ce, isapi

I want to be able to use the .html extension to render ASP pages.

I am using Windows CE 6 at the moment with the default web server, ASP 
is turned on.

My registry key looks like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\HTTPD\ScriptMap` with the following string key value pair added `.html` = `\\Windows\\asp.dll`.  After doing this all my .html files gave a 403 error.

**Update:**

To get this working do the following:
Add `.html` = `\Windows\asp.dll` (note single slashes) into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\HTTPD\ScriptMap` -> Double slashes are only required if you are adding via code.

If you get a 403 error then [check your permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885807(v=MSDN.10).aspx) to ensure scripts can be ran.

Comment: Just a few suggestions: Did you do a debug build and open the relevant debug zones? it might shed some new light.
Are you able to render asp pages that have other file extensions? Maybe there is a specific problem with the `.html` extension.

Comment: `.asp` pages render file but I cannot get it to render as any other page, even with an arbitrary extensions.

Comment: You lost me with the subkey<->key/pair: the article specifically says that there should be a key called `ScriptMap` under `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\HTTPD]` and that the mappings are values under that key. This seems to be what you are doing in the update. I fail to understand what you did before. Anyway, I am out of ideas for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backlashes. Use `"\\Windows\\asp.dll"` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot check until Monday though... I hope it is something as silly as that!!

Comment: Good luck! I've noticed that the CE web server can be finicky about some of its registry settings.

Comment: @Emanuel - it turns out I already escape the backslashes but to no avail.  Can you think of anything else it could be?

Comment: Since you're getting a 403, I'm guessing there may be a conflict with the permissions[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms900420(v=MSDN.10).aspx] for the virtual path where the .html files "live".

Comment: This makes sense... I have gone through all my VROOTS and removed the P setting so that everything is allowed.  I still get the forbidden error though.  Thanks for all your help, I feel like I'm close...

Comment: After some fiddling I have it working.  I'll update my question with the result but mark you as answered as you pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be doing this through the comments so here are my thoughts:

- Are you able to have a debug build that might print some additional information about the file association?
- How are you changing the registry? Do you have a persistent registry? Are you building the image with the specified registry key?
- After changing the registry key (in case you are not building the image with it and in case you do not have a persistent registry) - did you restart the server so it will read the registry settings again?

Comment: I am unable to do a debug build at the minute.  I am changing the registry via a simple registry editor.  The changes are permanent and I reboot the box after updating the registry to ensure the services have the new settings.  FYI I was fiddling around and got it to the point where I was receiving 403 errors on all .html files... Updated question with more info. Thanks